# convert unix timestamp to date in android shell

Tags: shell, timestamps, android

I try to convert a Debian Timestamp to a date in Android shell (Tasker) like:

date -d @1487411077

But getting some errors.

How to do that?

The Tasker error looks like:

```
12.32.45/Variables doreplresult: |sh date -d @%last| -> |sh date -d @1487411077
|
12.32.45/Variables doreplresult: |sh date -d @%last| -> |sh date -d @1487411077
|
12.32.45/E Shell Ausführen: %last -> %last
12.32.45/E Shell Ausführen:  -> 
12.32.45/E Shell Ausführen:  -> 
12.32.45/Shell runBackground sh date -d @1487411077
 root: true timeout: -1
12.32.45/Shell start process-thread ID 1013
12.32.45/E add wait type Shell1 time 2147483647
12.32.45/E add wait type Shell1 done
12.32.45/E add wait task
12.32.45/Variables doreplresult: |%last| -> |%last|
12.32.45/E Fehler: 127
```

Edit:

Android date is busybox and the I have to use `busybox date -d @1487411077`

Comment: Add error messages to quesion

Comment: I have edit my question. I use Tasker so I only can give you the Tasker error output!

Comment: What happens if you run other commands? Do some experiments; You may find the problem is with `tasker` (not with `date`).

Comment: I have not used tasker (or know what it is), or read German. However I thing that the message says there is something wrong with `%last`. What happens if you put in a literal as in you question, as opposed to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

As Android's `date` is `busybox` `date`, you should be able to do:

```
date -D%s -d 1487411077
```

`-D` was added in 2006, while support for `-d@<epoch>` à la GNU was added in 2010.

Comment: `busybox date -d @1487411077` gives Sat Feb 18 09:44:37 GMT 2017.